# Mixing assignment and compound assignment operators - Precedence?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure out, will chaining together assignment and compound assignment operators always work predictably from right-to-left? Example:

```
a = b += c
```

Will this always be evaluated as

```
a = (b += c)
```

no matter what other compound operators and order of operators I substitute?

There have been several times today when I have been hesitant to chain these various operators together without knowing for sure how the precedence will be evaluated. The [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) I usually reference is ambiguous, because it says that, even though these operators have the same precedence level, that "an operator which is listed on some row will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it." - this suggests that the plain assignment operator might be "bound tighter" to `a` & `b` than the compound assignment operator is to `b` and `c` in the example above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the assignment operators have the same precedence, and they group right-to-left.

Semantically, the `+=` operator is a combination of `=` and `+`, but syntactically it's an operator by itself, and it's the syntax that determines the precedence.

Quoting the C++ standard, the syntax is:

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    throw-expression

assignment-operator: one of
     = *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ^= |=
```

The C syntax is a bit simpler:

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

In C++, an *initializer-clause* is either an *assignment-expression* or a *braced-init-list*; the C grammar makes it clearer that the right operand can be an *assignment-expression*, which makes it right-associative.

Comment: @user2864740: `a *= b += c` is equivalent to `a *= (b += c)` (since they group right-to-left).

Answer (score 0):

"a row further below it" doesn't refer to `+=` appearing on the *line* below `=`, it refers to `throw` and `,` appearing on the *row* below it, with a table rows separated by borders.

The only way in which `a = b += c` can mean anything other than `(a) = ((b) += (c))`, assuming `a`, `b` and `c` are all valid expressions, is if any of those expressions contain operators that the page you link to lists as precedence level 15 or higher.

An example of that would be if `b` is actually the expression `d, e`: `a = d, e += c` naturally means `(a = d), (e += c)`, not `a = ((d, e) += c`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think the source I linked is confusing because it uses the example of *p++ which has two operators that I thought were in the same cell, but it's talking about them being in different rows. I now see that the postfix operator ++ has higher precedence than the prefix operator ++